# File-based installation of Node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm temporarily stuck on a Windows machine on which I have no administrator privileges. I would like to get node.js "installed" in a directory without using an installer, which requires elevation. On the node.js site, I don't see this distribution option.

Is anyone aware of a file-based (zip, self-extracting exe, etc) download that I can use to run node.js without using an installer on a Windows machine? Is there a way to run the installer without administrator elevation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, it turns out that the EXE download for Windows is all that node.js needs to run. I had thought that that was an exe for doing an installation. Just running the downloaded .exe works.

Comment: As of April 2014, the .EXE download will give you the Node REPL but not NPM.  The full .MSI installer (requires Admin Rights/elevation) will give you NPM also.